# Describing an unprecedented event with surprising result(s)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the best word for describing an unprecedented event that comes with surprising result(s), such as a new scientific achievement (e.g. journey to moon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ***[breakthrough](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breakthrough):***

> - A major achievement or success that permits further progress, as in technology.
> - A significant or sudden advance, development, etc., as in scientific knowledge.

The Free Dictionary

- 10 Most Important ***[Breakthroughs](http://www.themost10.com/important-breakthroughs-in-space-exploration/)*** in Space Exploration

> - The landing of Philae space craft on the surface of a moving comet for the first time has been hailed as one of the greatest scientific achievements of our lifetime, and got us thinking about all the other major breakthroughs in our exploration of space which have taken place up to now.

(themost10.com)

Comment: What about _Groundbreaking_  as in "**a groundbreaking achievement**".

Comment: It works, note that breakthrough is a noun, while groundbreaking ( related to innovation) is  an adjective.